# How to stop my loop after clicking a particular element

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

My web page have system views that have the same xpath. 
Elements:

```html
<span class="ms-crm-VS-header-MenuItem-Title ms-crm-VS-header-MenuItem-Title-Rest" title="System Views">Accounts Being Followed</span>
<span class="ms-crm-VS-header-MenuItem-Title ms-crm-VS-header-MenuItem-Title-Rest" title="System Views">Accounts I Follow</span>
<span class="ms-crm-VS-header-MenuItem-Title ms-crm-VS-header-MenuItem-Title-Rest" title="System Views">Active Accounts</span>
<span class="ms-crm-VS-header-MenuItem-Title ms-crm-VS-header-MenuItem-Title-Rest" title="System Views">Create Personal View</span>
<span class="ms-crm-VS-header-MenuItem-Title ms-crm-VS-header-MenuItem-Title-Rest" title="System Views">My Active Accounts</span>
<span class="ms-crm-VS-header-MenuItem-Title ms-crm-VS-header-MenuItem-Title-Rest" title="System Views">My Connections</span>
<span class="ms-crm-VS-header-MenuItem-Title ms-crm-VS-header-MenuItem-Title-Rest" title="System Views">System Views</span>
```

Their xpath is:

```
//ul[contains(@class, 'ms-crm-VS-Menu')]/li/a[2]/span/nobr/span
```

I want to open each of the view but want to stop after opening a particular view. I tried with the below code, but my code is opening all the system views. Can somebody please help:

```
            IList<IWebElement> elements = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//ul[contains(@class, 'ms-crm-VS-Menu')]/li/a[2]/span/nobr/span"));
        foreach (IWebElement eachelement in elements)
        {
            if (eachelement.Text.Equals("Create Personal View"))
            { break; }
            executor.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].click();", eachelement);

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully below snippet should work

```
List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//span[contains(@class, 'ms-crm-VS-header-MenuItem-Title ms-crm-VS-header-MenuItem-Title-Rest')]"));
    for(WebElement ele : elements){
        //System.out.println(ele.getText());
            JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
            executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", ele);
            if (ele.getText().equals("Create Personal View")){
                break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hello @prithvi394 ... Modified the code and I still have the same issue. The loop is not being terminated.

Comment: Uncomment the SOPL statement and check the output for each pass. The code worked on machine. The control will come out of while loop if it enters the If loop.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
   IList<IWebElement> elements = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//ul[contains(@class, 'ms-crm-VS-Menu')]/li/a[2]/span/nobr/span"));
        foreach (IWebElement eachelement in elements)
        {
            if (GetInnerHtml(eachelement)=="Create Personal View")
            { break; }
            executor.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].click();", eachelement);

            }
        }

public static string GetInnerHtml(IWebElement element)
{
    var remoteWebDriver = (RemoteWebElement)element;
    var javaScriptExecutor = (IJavaScriptExecutor) remoteWebDriver.WrappedDriver;
    var innerHtml = javaScriptExecutor.ExecuteScript("return arguments[0].innerHTML;", element).ToString();

    return innerHtml;
}
```